# show html text on modal window (not parsing)

Tags: jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I am making a little website with examples of HTML and CSS spinners and loaders.
When we click on one of the examples a modal window opens. I want to display on this modal window the HTML and CSS code of that particular spinner, so people can copy it and use it on their projects.

I am loading the correct "text" for each spinner/modal window using the .load() in jQuery, like this:

```
$(".htmlcode").load("content/" + fileName + ".html");
```

this is loading the correct file and html data.

**The problem is** that the HTML is parsing, so instead os showing the "html text" it is showing again the animation.

What would be the best way to do this?

There is another website with similar functionality: http://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see how you're loading in the content - it would perhaps be best to create a `<textarea>` component in the modal window, then set the content of the textarea to that of the html/css.

That way, it would be escaped.

```
    function copy() {
document.getElementById("myTextAreaID").value = document.getElementById("myhtml").innerHTML;
}
```

Crude working example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/825osa3d/

EDIT:  Further work to broaden the concept to convert the HTML of an element to character codes, then plonk it into a DIV

https://jsfiddle.net/2fubppkp/3/

Comment: that is a good idea, but i think i would then have to find a way to change the text area size according to the content (some animation have much more css and html than others).
I will try putting the html inside <xmp> tags, maybe that will work.  ;)

Comment: Based on that, I've made a reasonable over-worked-in-the-wrong-areas fiddle that explores the concept a little more...(see edit)

Comment: that looks great, thanks! I ended up using the <xmp> tags. It think for the project and functionality i had in mind it was good. You can check out how i used it here: [Spinners](https://boguz.github.io/Spinners)

Comment: Good work!  Just as a heads up, your Google Font isn't loading as the link is over https, whilst Google Fonts aren't (so it gets blocked in browser).

Comment: thanks. i chave changed the code for the fonts. does it work ok for you now?